# How to install interdependent repository?

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm

My yum is not working properly and I don't know why. I already am into production and cannot restart. I am trying to install libjpeg-turbo from rpm and yum is not able to find dependency. The dependency is libjpeg-turbo-devel as well.

Command I have used:

```
 yum install 
 http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64.rpm

 http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

---

```
 Package: libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.1-1.el6.x86_64 (/libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.1-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 1.2.1-1.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Comment: Why don't you just install the packages normally?

Comment: @Michael Normally means? I don't have rhel subscription. Accidentally used rhel. I will soon migrate to centos.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Actually I was installing postgis. It required libjpeg's .so file but although i had libjpeg installed it didn't find it out. That's why I am updating it to libjpeg-turbo.

Comment: Why on earth would you do this and not make a new server without this messiness?  It will probably save you hours.

Comment: @FalconMomot As you may have know I am new to linux environment. I don't know what messiness is here? After all I am installing software! May be I am doing it wrong way. what is the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localinstall installs a local package that's already been downloaded. Install will reach out to a repository and download the package...

All you really need to do here is let Yum do its thing:

```
yum install libjpeg-turbo libjpeg-turbo-devel
```

That's it.

Comment: I did that but from remote rpm. when I do yum install libjpeg-turbo libjpeg-turbo-devel then I get "No package libjpeg-turbo available.".

Comment: Then your packages are likely installed. Verify this with `rpm -qi libjpeg-turbo` and `rpm -qi libjpeg-turbo-devel`

Comment: I get "package libjpeg-turbo is not installed" and package libjpeg-turbo-devel is not installed from those command

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running the install using a local package file (if not, yum would solve the deoendency for you).

Just install both in one same command, like :

```
yum localinstall libjpeg-turbo*.rpm
```